# Create partition on a table is having 2 primary keys in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am creating partition on a table that is having 2 primary keys.

```
USE DB_New
GO
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION JKeyRangePF (Int)
AS RANGE Left FOR VALUES (50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600,650,700,750)
GO
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME JKeyRangeScheme 
AS PARTITION JKeyRangePF ALL TO ([JKey]) 
GO
```

The problem is `PK_RESULTS` is made up of 2 primary keys

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TESTTAB DROP CONSTRAINT PK_RESULTS
GO
```

When I drop the constraint `PK_RESULTS`, the clustered index is dropped on both the primary keys.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TESTTAB ADD CONSTRAINT PK_RESULTS PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED  ([JKey])
   WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Did you mean "The Problem is PK_RESULTS is made up of 2 *columns*"?

Comment: Also tags & title don't match.

Comment: You *cannot* have two primary keys in a table - this is impossible. What you have is **one** primary key that consists of **two columns**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is quite explicit about partition functions:

> Only one partitioning column, specified in a CREATE TABLE or CREATE
>   INDEX statement, can be used.

You could swap the order of the columns in the PK definition.  Would that give you a single-column partitioning scheme more suited to your needs?

If partitioning on the single, highest-order column in your PK isn't sufficient you could combine the two current PK columns into a new, synthetic column, make that the PK and partition on that.  If your current table is this (in pseudo-sql):

```
MyTable (ID int, SecondPK char(5), OtherCols varchar(xx)) PK (ID, SecondPK)
```

.. you could change it to

```
MyTable (
    MadeUpKey char(20),
    ID int,
    SecondPK char(5),
    OtherCols varchar(xx))
  PK (MadeUpKey),
  Unique (ID, SecondPK)
```

Set `MadeUpKey` to `convert(varchar(20), ID) + SecondPK`, perhaps with zero padding, whenever you insert a row.

I'd strongly suggest you test thoroughly with the current approach and ensure it does *not* meet your requirements before you start on such a convoluted exercise, though.